# Are delivery reports a mandatory part of the SMS protocol?

Tags: sms, protocols

Some phone companies disable reception of SMS delivery reports, allegedly to cut costs. I'd like to know if eliminating such facility could be considered a violation of the SMS protocol, or if this is an optional feature.

I couldn't find an authoritative source about the protocol. [RFC 5724](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5724.txt) is about SMS URIs, but not the protocol itself, and I found something about [3GPP](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/23040.htm), but it seems more like an implementation guide than an actual specification. Besides, it's a Word document, which seems to me unlikely to contain the "official" specification.